# Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database - MySQL Access denied error

Tags: drush

I've installed Drush 7 using Composer and working with Drupal 8 and 7 on Ubuntu 12.04 with PHP 5.4.31, mysql 5.5.38

Drush will `dl` modules and themes just fine but when I want to `en` a module then it gives me the `Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database.`

So upon further investigation I did this:

```
$ drush -v -d sql-cli
Starting Drush preflight. [0.02 sec, 1.15 MB]                        [preflight]
Cache HIT cid:                                                           [debug]
7.0-dev-commandfiles-0-87f720da39665f2c425de5e651f2ac4d [0.05 sec,
1.19 MB]
Bootstrap to phase 0. [0.2 sec, 3.19 MB]                             [bootstrap]
Bootstrap to phase 0. [0.28 sec, 3.19 MB]                            [bootstrap]
Found command: sql-cli (commandfile=sql) [0.28 sec, 3.19 MB]         [bootstrap]
Calling hook drush_sql_cli [0.56 sec, 3.21 MB]                           [debug]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_root() [0.56 sec,    [bootstrap]
3.22 MB]
Initialized Drupal 8.0-dev root directory at                            [notice]
/home/wavesailor/My_sites/bootstrap-business [0.62 sec, 3.52 MB]
Cache HIT cid:                                                           [debug]
7.0-dev-commandfiles-1-67528d048330f8c38ed66ea20e647906 [0.62 sec,
3.52 MB]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_site() [0.63 sec,    [bootstrap]
3.57 MB]
Initialized Drupal site default at sites/default [0.63 sec, 3.57 MB]    [notice]
Cache MISS cid:                                                          [debug]
7.0-dev-install_profile-66ecfeb9791a023150773849f1550c5d [0.64 sec,
3.57 MB]
Cache HIT cid:                                                           [debug]
7.0-dev-commandfiles-2-027a7d06ad1248d56c7499a21fb8d2df [0.65 sec,
3.57 MB]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_configuration() [0.65[bootstrap]
sec, 3.57 MB]
Calling proc_open(mysql --defaults-extra-file=/tmp/drush_ST3u9r --database=bootstrap_business --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3306);
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'my_username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Returned from hook drush_sql_cli [0.87 sec, 3.72 MB]                     [debug]
Command dispatch complete [0.87 sec, 3.71 MB]                           [notice]
Peak memory usage was 5.21 MB [0.87 sec, 3.7 MB]                        [memory]
$
```

It seems it cannot connect to the database so I did the following:

```
$ drush sql-connect
mysql --user=my_username --password=my_password --database=bootstrap_business --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3306
$ mysql --user=my_username --password=my_password --database=bootstrap_business --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3306
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 286
Server version: 5.5.38-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

I can connect manually to the database with the connection string given by drush.

So then I deleted the `.drush` folder in my home directory but that did not help.
I did try this for both Drupal 7 and 8 sites.

So then I downgraded to drush 6 (`composer global require drush/drush:6.*`) and drush then worked flawlessly with Drupal 7 sites. I then upgraded to drush 7 (`composer global require drush/drush:dev-master`) and it stops working again

Any ideas on how to solve this??

Comment: From within the composer directory, try to run `composer update` and see if it's updating the Drush dependency. If it does, chances are that your issue will be fixed by updating.

Comment: @anavarre - Thanks but that didn't help

Comment: Okay. When Drush is calling proc_open() it'll create a file under /tmp/drush_RANDOMTEXT - Does that file contain the correct credentials to your database?

Comment: @anavarre The file is deleted I think - I'm not sure how to stop it from being deleted to view it

Comment: @anavarre - Finally solved it - see answer below. Thx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer to the problem was that I had a file `.my.cnf` in my home directory which I used a while back. It contained the `user=username` and the `password=old_password`. This was the cause of problem as it contained the correct username but an old password.

Previous drush versions (< 7.x) did not use the mysql option `--defaults-extra-file=/tmp/mysql_credentials` to connect to database and that's why the problem didn't exist when I used an older version of drush.

I would have thought that the '`--defaults-extra-file=/tmp/mysql_credentials` would supercede the `.my.cnf` in my home directory but it doesn't seem to.

One thing which would be useful to help debug this issue it to make drush not delete the `/tmp/...` files when you select the `-d` option.

Answer (score 1):

Do a `drush st database | grep -i connected`.

If you don't get any results, that could mean (in your case) the db credentials on your settings.php is wrong.

The above command tells drush to give a status (st) of your installation, filter results to include only strings containing the word *database* and finally passing this result to grep to do a case-insensitive search for the word *connected*. To understand more about `drush st` execute a `drush help st`.

Comment: It shows the correct settings except it does not connect. When I run `drush sql-connect` and use that output exactly as is, I connect to MySQL perfectly. That why this does not make sense to me??